# Select option not filled with values which are mapped from other table

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a mapping between two models, `Movie` and `Place`.
when i now create a from `movieForm` and fill in a already created `Movie` and open then a view with that `movieForm` all textfields and select's are populate except the value which mappes the `Place` to the `Movie`.
in the below example the categorie is correct selected in the "select" in the view but the place are not selected.

What can be the problem?
and how can i resolve this?

---

#### Movie Model

```
@Entity
public class Movie extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    ...
    @Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public EnumCategorie categorie = EnumCategorie.FILM;
    @ManyToOne
    public Place place;

    ...
}
```

#### Place Model

```
@Entity
public class Place extends Model {
    @Id
    public String name;
    ...
}
```

#### The Controller

```
public class Movies extends Controller {
    public static Result edit(Long id) {
        Movie movie = Movie.find.byId(id);
        Form<Movie> movieForm = form(Movie.class).fill(movie);
        return ok(movieCreate.render(movieForm,
                placeForm, "edit"));
    }
```

#### The View

```scala
@form(routes.Movies.save(option)) {
        <fieldset>
        ...
        @select(movieForm("categorie"),
            options(Movie.categories),
            '_label -> "Categories", '_default -> "-- Choose a categorie --",
            '_showConstraints -> false,
            'class -> "controls")
        @select(movieForm("place"),
            options(Place.places),
            '_label -> "Places", '_default -> "-- Choose a place --",
            '_showConstraints -> false,
            'class -> "controls")
        ...
        </fieldset>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed this line of code on your `Place.java` model. The model might be like below:

#### Place Model

```java
@Entity
public class Place extends Model {
   @Id
   public String name;

   ... // the rest of fields

   // Sample of all Places data as value of select option in views
   public static List<String> places() {
      List<String> all = new ArrayList<>();
      all.add("INA"); // Place.name = "INA"
      all.add("BEL"); // Place.name = "BEL"
      all.add("KOR"); // Place.name = "KOR"
      return all;
   }

   // You missed this 
   public String toString() {
      return name; // return Place.name
   }
}
```

---

Okay, now this is the explaination. Let see your view code on:

```
@select(movieForm("place"), options(Place.places), ...)
```

The `options(...)` only apply for data type below (taken from play2 source):

```
def apply(options: (String, String)*) = ...
def apply(options: Map[String, String]) = ...
def apply(options: java.util.Map[String, String]) = ...
def apply(options: List[String]) = ...
def apply(options: java.util.List[String]) = ...
```

Because your place field on `Movie` class is `Place` object rather than `String` object, so it should be represented as `String`. The way you can define it is to override `toString()` method on `Place` object, so it represent the `Place.name` value (**the ID** for `Place` model) as value of select option in view (referring to data that populated using `Place.places()`).

Hope this can help for solving your problem.

---

#### Update

We can also do something like following, if we choose not to override the `toString()` method on the Model:

```
`@select(movieForm("place.name"), options(Place.places), ...)`
```

`movieForm("place.name")` can be used for binding `Place` object with the ID value respectable to input value directly. [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802566/binding-form-request-with-manytoone-field-on-play-framework-2) may be as the reference for this solution.